# Design Pattern when using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have confusion on Design pattern when working with Entity Framework.
My current project has following pattern.

**Pattern1**: Each box represents a separate class library projects

[image: Pattern1]

Now a team member wants to introduce Entity Framework and suggests this:

**Pattern2**

[image: Pattern2]

I have seen several ASP.NET MVC web application samples where they keep DataContext and POCO classes in the same folders and no concept of logical service layer.

Pattern1 Argument: Want to keep POCO classes and low level DataAccess call separate.

Pattern2 Argument: To keep related code in one project promoting "less Cohesion", and "low coupling"

So I want to understand a bit more on these two patterns and when to use one over another.

Comment: I have seen many presentations and heard many opinions that less layers equals less mess. I believe that layer-over-layer architecture is many times an overkill.